# How to get Call Log by date in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, calllog

I am trying to get Call Logs by date. But get stuck with the format of the date to be passed to the cursor to get the values.

**Call Log Cursor**

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String selection = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " = "+dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());

Cursor mCallLogCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null,
            CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC");
```

Tried with various dateformatter type but none of them working.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                        CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls._ID },
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(sinceDate.getTime())},
                CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " asc");
```

`sinceDate` is a Date variable that is set to the beginning of the period you will want to cover.